# Can you edit csv files in excel, without excel changing the format of ""?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a lot of csv files which I'd like to batch edit in VBA macros (Excel 2010). They are comma separated and each value also has "" around. This is an example input:

```
"text","9","01/01/2020"
```

After editing this format cannot change, as other programs rely on it looking like that. Let's say I open the file in excel and change the 9 to 8 and then save. The excel saved output removes the "s like this:

```
text,8,01/01/2020
```

I have tried importing to excel while not counting " as a text qualifier, but saving after that the result looks like this

```
"""text""","""8""","""01/01/2020"""
```

I have tried forcing the values to be text through the text import wizard, but it didn't help.

So, is there a way to edit a csv file in excel, while also keeping the single " format after saving?

So far the best workaround I can think of is to open the """ output with something like notepad and do a Find & Replace for """ and ", but I find this a bit hard to automate.

Comment: A plain CSV doesn't need all values to be quoted; I'd think this is more an issue with whatever other programs you have reading the data. Excel keeps quotations only where they're required (for example, if the string itself contains comma characters), and it doesn't look like there's any generic way to change that. If you can't change your downstream programs, I'd stick to editing CSVs in a text-editing tool.

Comment: VBA itself can open the file as a text file, manipulate it and then re-save it without any need to invoke the text-import wizard at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It opens .csv file without quotes and save it with quotes (not using Excel SaveAs dialog). In between, you can do any modifications you need. The csv file is saved using the initial full name, but adding '_bis` at the end. I did that only for test reasons. If it will show like in my computer, you can close the csv and save it with your modifications and quotes, also...
Please, open the created csv file using Notepad.

Of course, after testing in this way you can use only the part adding quotes and saving the array as csv. I can make a function if needed. Taking like parameters the active sheet used range array and full path to the csv to be saved.

```
Sub OpenTextNoQuotesSaveWithQuotes()
Dim csvFullName As String, arr As Variant, arr1 As Variant
   csvFullName = "csvFileFullPath" 'use here your csv file full path
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=csvFullName, Origin:= _
        437, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True

   'do whatewer modifications needed here...
   '......................................

   'add doublequotes:
   Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1): arr = sh.UsedRange.Value
  ReDim arr1(UBound(arr, 1) - 1, UBound(arr, 2) - 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
     For j = 0 To UBound(arr, 2) - 1
        arr1(i - 1, j) = Chr(34) & arr(i, j + 1) & Chr(34)
     Next
  Next i

  'create .CSV comma delimited
  Dim newF As String, FileNum, strRow As String
  newF = Left(csvFullName, Len(csvFullName) - 4) & "_bis.csv"
  FileNum = FreeFile()
  Open newF For Output As #FileNum
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr1, 1)
      For j = 0 To UBound(arr1, 2)
        strRow = strRow & arr1(i, j) & "," ' arr1(i, 0) & "," & arr1(i, 1) & "," & arr1(i, 2) & _
                                        arr1(i, 3) & "," & arr1(i, 4)
      Next j
       strRow = Left(strRow, Len(strRow) - 1)
        Print #FileNum, strRow: strRow = ""
    Next i
  Close #FileNum
End Sub
```